# Extract values from feature class to points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, arcgis-10.3, feature-class

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1. I have a polygon feature class along with a point feature class. I want to extract values from one field of my polygon feature class to my points.

To specify, I have a geologic map (so basically a polygon feature class) with a RockType field in its attribute table. I have a bunch of points and I want to know what the RockType of each point is based on the polygon feature class that has the RockType field.

I know of the Extract Values to Points and Extract Values to Table tools, but those both require raster datasets, which I do not have. I'm wondering whether extraction by feature class is possible in ArcMap. If so, what tools/codes do I need to perform this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000034000000.htm) This will join attributes from one feature class to another based on spatial location.So you can join the RockType attribute to any points that fall inside of the polygons.

Answer (score -1):

After you have done the Spatial Join as was already mentioned you can make a selection of the points will a  value and field calculate the data from your polygon. Make sure your fields match and will accept your bulk data load.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why my profile did not load correctly but my answer was posted as ^user56626. I apologize for the confusion.